# Why is my diffuse lighting changing with camera position?

Tags: opengl, camera, lighting

I am trying to do lighting in view space, but I am afraid I have an issue. I calculate the normals as:

```
N = norm_mat * vec4(vert_norm,0.0)
```

where `norm_mat` is the `transpose(inverse(model_view_mat))`.

Then in the lighting shader (for a directional light) perform the following:

```
N = normalize(N.xyz);
vec4 view_L_pos =  vec4(lightPosition.xyz, 0.0) * view_mat;
vec3 L = normalize(view_L_pos.xyz);
out_col = vec3(dot(N,L))
```

However, moving the camera changes the floor's lighting:

[image: floor-level camera view]

[image: high-up camera view]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: one thing that definitely won't work as intended: vec4 view_L_pos =  vec4(lightPosition.xyz, 0.0) * view_mat; -> the order is wrong, the mat must come first.

Comment: Normals need to be transformed same as the vertices but without translation. (Side note -- for a rotation-only matrix, inversion and transposition are the same... so "transpose(inverse(model_view_mat))" is probably a no-op.)

Comment: @davidvanbrink thanks for the trick about the orthogonality, but isn't the w set 0 enough to get rid of translation? With the correction made by gemse it seems to work fine

Comment: @davidvanbrink: That `transpose (inverse (...))` technique is designed to accommodate modelview matrices with non-uniform scaling. It is absolutely true that if the matrix contains only rotation and no scaling that it will always do nothing, but if there is scaling in the matrix, then it is a very important step. So the "normal matrix" is (in order to work with all possible cases) defined as the inverse transpose of the top-left 3x3 matrix. You can see why [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html).